# Pass an items prop with the items within the category key

Tags: reactjs

I can't seem to pass certain items into an `item` prop if they relate to the category that I am looping through

I have a `JSON` like this:

```
{
  "Categories": [
    {
      "Name": "Music",
    },
    {
      "Name": "Comedy",
    },
    {
      "Name": "Sport",
    },
    {
      "Name": "Family",
    },
  ],
  "Items": [
    {
      "Name": "Dolly Parton",
      "NameId": "dolly-parton",
      "Category": "Music",
    },
    {
      "Name": "Cee Lo Green",
      "NameId": "cee-lo-green",
      "Category": "Music",
    },
    {
      "Name": "Take That",
      "NameId": "take-that",
      "Category": "Music",
    },
    {
      "Name": "Football",
      "NameId": "football",
      "Category": "Sport",
    },
    {
      "Name": "Hockey",
      "NameId": "hockey",
      "Category": "Sport",
    }
    ]
}
```

I'm looping through all the categories and then printing them into a list while trying to only pass items that relate to that category in an `items` prop. I have the code below but it is passing all my data to each element and I'm not sure why.

```
class CategoryItems extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    state = {
        items: this.props.items,
        categories: this.props.categories,
    };

    render() {
        const items = this.state.items;

        return (
            <section className="category-wrapper">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="category-wrapper__inner">
                        {this.state.categories.map((category, index) => (
                            <CategoryItem
                                key={category.Name}
                                items={items.map((item, index) => {
                                    item.Category === category.Name ? item : '';
                                })}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        );
    }
}
```

All the data is there and in the react dev-tools it says each element has 667 items but I know there should only be 7 items on the sports category.

Comment: Please try    {this.state.categories.map((category, index) => (
        <CategoryItem
            key={category.Name}
            items.find((item) => item.Category === category.Name).map((item, index) => {
                item
            })}
        />
    ))}

Comment: `item.Category === category.Name ? item : '';` You're creating an item even if `item.Category !== category.Name`.

Answer (score 1):

Apply a filter instead of a map.

```
<CategoryItem
  key={category.Name}
  items={items.filter(i => item.Category === category.Name)}
/>
```

Comment: Glad to help, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ,

```
class CategoryItems extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

state = {
    items: this.props.items,
    categories: this.props.categories,
};


render() {
    const items = this.state.items;
    const renderList = this.state.categories.reduce((total, category) => {
      const list = items.filter(item => item.Category === category.Name);
        if(list.length > 0){
          total.push(<CategoryItem
            key={category.Name}
            items={list}
        />);
        }
        return total
    },[])
    return (
        <section className="category-wrapper">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="category-wrapper__inner">
                  {renderList}
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}
```

}